# dropdown list inside a table goes under columns

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, drop-down-menu

I have a table in which a sticky column contains dropdown list. my problem is dropdown list goes under the column in next row onwards can anyone help me
I have two columns position sticky because i don't want them to moved while scrolling.In one fixed column I have a dropdown list while I'm clicking on dropdown it goes under the sticky element
below is the code can someone help me

I tried adding z-index but it seems not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the right declarations from these 2 sections:

```
    .fixedit{
    position: sticky;
    width: 10px;
}

.fixactivate{
    position: sticky;
}
```

Also changing your white space to nowrap might help too in this section

```
    .hex-table-scroll .hex-table tbody tr td {
    word-wrap: break-word;
    word-break: break-all;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: without removing position:sticky is there any other method

Comment: I didn't remove position:sticky.  Maybe leave the fixedit and fixactivate alone then and just change the white-space to nowrap.

Comment: Here's an example of doing just that. https://jsfiddle.net/ko7u0xpt/

Comment: And here's the fiddle of doing all 3 changes I had in my answer. https://jsfiddle.net/ko7u0xpt/1/

Comment: I need to remove that column from scrolling that is why i positioned right.
without removing that can i fix?

Comment: Yes, don't change that part then. Only add the white-space: nowrap; leave the other sections alone.